# Add event listener on QGraphicsEllipseItem

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm creating a QGis Plugin in python which has a `QGraphicsView` in which I draw and ellipse on which I want to detect if the user clicks.

I know the ellipse inherits `QGraphicsItem` which has a `mouseReleaseEvent` but I just don't know how to listen for an event.

```
self.scene = QGraphicsScene() //form.py

ellipse = self.dock.scene.addEllipse(0, 0, 100, 100, QPen(), QBrush()) //plugin.py

//now that i've got a reference to the ellipse how do I detect when someone clicks on it ?
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to override a `mouseReleaseEvent` in `QGraphicsScene`.

```
class MyScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        # here you should do something with your scene if mouse button was released
```

then create scene with:

```
self.scene = MyScene()
```

Comment: Thank you, but this triggers when i click on the scene, not on the item in it(in this case the ellipse). Any ideas on how to get the item and not the scene ?

Comment: You have to check whether your eclipse (`boundingRect()`) contains clicked point. First get clicked point coordinates, then calculate eclipse bounding box coordinates, check if contains, then do something what you want. This code should go under `mouseReleaseEvent` of course.